# Облачный сервер, как заставить приложение работать без моего ПК

Tags: javascript, reactjs, сервер, ssh, веб-сервер

У меня есть проект, он лежит на облачном сервере, папка server - отвечает за сервер, там я разворачиваю сервер на express, запустить код из это папки можно с помощью npm run dev, также у меня есть папка client - которая отвечает за фронтенд на реакте, запускается этот код с помощью npm start. Я подключаюсь с помощью ssh к серверу и ввожу там эти команды для запуска кода. Если я закрою консоль с запуском сервера, он продолжает работать, но если я закрываю консоль, где я запускал npm start, то сайт перестает работать. Как реализовать запуск приложения например единоразово, чтобы я мог выключить свой ПК и приложение продолжало работать на сервере

Comment: Npm start запускает только не собранное приложение. собрать его нужно с помощью npm run build. А дальше уже размещать. Где? Я уже не знаю. Я только на хостинг выкладывал и на гитхаб Пейдж. С сервером не знаю, наверное тоже что-то нужно делать